# CSS <li> does not extend

Tags: html, css, list, flexbox, html-lists

I have `<ul>` list and inside `<li>` i have link `<a href="...">`

I want the `<li>` not to be influenced by the content and have fixed size.

**My CSS**

```
 ul.files {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}

ul.files li {
    display: inline;

}


ul.files li a { 

    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 0 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<ul class="files">
  <li>
    <a id="some_id" href="http">123</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to set fixed `width` and `height` to `<li>` you need to change `display: inline;` to `inline-block`

```
ul.files li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

**To center text**

To center content of `li` you can use `display: inline-flex`

```
ul.files li {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: It's work. How center text <a id="some_id" href="http">123</a> ?